# Is there a way to support dotnet user-jwt generated tokens in .net 6 webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm trying to support tokens generated with user-jwt (for local development) as well as tokens generated from another source. It works in .net 7 but I am trying to support both in a .net 6 webapi project.

I have gone down the path of adding auth configs as below thinking that when it tries to validate the token with the local config, I cold validate the token myself.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("jwtAuth1", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = authSettings.Schemes.Bearer.ValidIssuer;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = authSettings.Schemes.Bearer.ValidIssuer,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("message received");
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers.Authorization))
                        {
                            Log.Logger.Debug("Authorization header is empty");
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("Authentication Failed: {ExceptionMessage} {Token}", context.Exception.Message,
                            context.Request.Headers.Authorization);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("token validated");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnForbidden = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("OnForbidden");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("OnChallenge cognito");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("local", options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    //ValidIssuer = authSettings.Schemes.Bearer.ValidIssuer,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    SignatureValidator = (token, parameters) =>
                    {
                        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
                        return jwt;
                    }
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("message received local");
                        //context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("Token validated with local");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("Token failed with local");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnForbidden = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("Token forbidden with local");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Debug("Token challenge with local");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

and have set the auth policy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("jwtAuth1", "local")
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
```

and the challenge event is fired for both policies, but I can't figure out how to authorize the "local" token.

Has anyone else found a way to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Phoesion.DevJwt](https://github.com/Phoesion/Phoesion.DevJwt) for generating/consuming tokens for development/testing.

#### Service Setup

1. install the [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Phoesion.DevJwt)

```
dotnet add package Phoesion.DevJwt
```

2. add this line in your jwt auth setup

```cs
.AddJwtBearer(o => o.UseDevJwt(builder.Environment));
```

that adds an `ISecurityTokenValidator` for validating the dev tokens.
*( It needs the `HostingEnvironment` so it only adds this handler in Development/Testing environments )*

#### Token generation

1. install the dotnet tool

```bash
dotnet tool install --global phoesion.devjwt.cli
```

2. generate tokens using

```
dotnet devjwt create myApi --email user@mail.com --sub 42
```

*Disclosure : I am the developer of this library*